# SilverStripe - Maintain dropdown selected content when hitting back button

Tags: php, jquery, silverstripe

I have a list of articles that can be sorted by year based on a dropdown list of years. I asked about this and got an amazing answer back, but now I notice one issue: whenever the user clicks "back" the list of articles always resets to the default view (which is to display all articles). However, the dropdown list "remembers" the selection the user made. I would like the article listing to match the select year in the dropdown to keeps things consistent and easy for the user (I don't want them to have to reselect the year they originally chose every time they hit the back button on an article).

I know I could use session variables, but that I wonder if that's really necessary? Or maybe that is the easier route to take considering how the code is setup?

Here is the code I have for the NewsReleasesPage template:

```
<?php

class NewsReleasesPage extends Page
{
    private static $db = array();

    private static $has_one = array();
}

class NewsReleasesPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'PaginatedReleases',
        'YearFilterForm',
        'handleYearRequest',
        'doFilter',
        'year',
        'index'
    );

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }


    public function handleYearRequest(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
    {
        $year = $request->param('ID');
        $data = array(
            'Year' => $year,
            'PaginatedReleases' => $this->PaginatedReleases($year)
        );

        if ($request->isAjax()) {
            // in case of an ajax request, render only the partial template
            return $this->renderWith('ArticleList', $data);
        } else {
            // returning an array will cause the page to render normally
            return $data;
        }
    }

    //creates a form to filter through news releases by year
    public function YearFilterForm()
    {
        // get an array of all distinct years
        $list = SQLSelect::create()
            ->addFrom('NewsReleaseArticlePage')
            ->selectField('YEAR("ArticleDate")', 'Year')
            ->setOrderBy('Year', 'DESC')
            ->addGroupBy('"Year"')->execute()->column('Year');

        // create an associative array with years as keys & values
        $values = array_combine($list, $list);

        // our fields just contain the dropdown, which uses the year values
        $fields = FieldList::create(array(
            DropdownField::create(
                'Year',
                '',
                $values,
                $this->getRequest()->param('ID')
            )->setHasEmptyDefault(true)->setEmptyString('Show all')
        ));

        $actions = FieldList::create(array(
            FormAction::create('doFilter', 'Submit')
        ));

        return Form::create($this, 'YearFilterForm', $fields, $actions);
    }

    public function year()
    {
        return $this->handleYearRequest($this->request);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->handleYearRequest($this->request);
    }

    //redirects to the proper url depending on which year is selected for sorting news
    public function doFilter($data, $form)
    {
        if (empty($data['Year'])) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Link());
        } else {
            return $this->redirect($this->Link('year/' . $data['Year']));
        }
    }

    //created a paginated list of news released by year
    public function PaginatedReleases($year = null)
    {
        $list = NewsReleaseArticlePage::get()->sort('ArticleDate', 'DESC');
        if ($year) {
            $list = $list->where(array('YEAR("ArticleDate") = ?' => $year));
        }
        return PaginatedList::create($list, $this->getRequest())->setLimitItems(0);
    }

}
```

Here is the jQuery related to this:

```
(function($) {
    $(function(){
        // hide form actions, as we want to trigger form submittal
        // automatically when dropdown changes
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").find(".Actions").hide();

        // bind a change event on the dropdown to automatically submit
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("change", "select", function (e) {
            $("#Form_YearFilterForm").submit();
        });

        // handle form submit events
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            // submit form via ajax
            $.post(
                form.attr("action"),
                form.serialize(),
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );
            return false;
        });

        // handle pagination clicks
        $("body").on("click", "a.pagination", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            $.get(
                $(this).attr("href"),
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );

            return false;
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

And then the SilverStripe template file that renders the listing:

```
<div id="box3" class="clearfix">
    <div id="Box-Main-Right" class="clearfix">
        <p class="Text-Intro">$H1</p>
        $YearFilterForm
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Box-LEADING-BRANDS clearfix">
    <div class="Box-Main-Right1 clearfix">
        <% include ArticleList %>
    </div>
</div>
$Form
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting this problem, because the form starts in a state that's different from the default when the page loads and thus the content (loaded via JS) is out of sync with the form-field.

A simple – albeit somewhat hacky – approach would be to just submit the form via JS if the dropdown value differs from the default (eg. when it's not an empty value). You can do this by altering your JS code as below:

```
// handle form submit events
$("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("submit", function(e){
    // removed code for brevity
});

// NEW CODE TO ADD
// If the dropdown has a value (eg. is not empty), submit it.
if($("#Form_YearFilterForm select").val()){
    $("#Form_YearFilterForm").submit();
}
```

---

The *proper* way to do this, would be to make your JavaScript code work with URL changes. You can do this by utilizing the [History API](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js). So you would rewrite your JS code as follows:

```
;(function($) {
    $(function(){
        // Establish Variables
        var History = window.History,
            State = History.getState();

        // hide form actions, as we want to trigger form submittal
        // automatically when dropdown changes
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm .Actions").hide();

        // bind a change event on the dropdown to automatically submit
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("change", 'select[name="Year"]', function(e){
            $("#Form_YearFilterForm").submit();
        });

        // handle form submit events
        $("#Form_YearFilterForm").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dropdown = $(this).find('select[name="Year"]');
            var year = dropdown.val();
            // Add a new history state where we keep the year as a property
            // and use the urlpattern to build our target URL
            History.pushState(
                { year: year },
                null,
                dropdown.data("urlpattern").replace(/YYYY$/, year)
            );
            return false;
        });

        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){
            // Whenever the URL changes, we load the proper data via AJAX
            // and set the dropdown value accordingly
            State = History.getState();
            $('#Form_YearFilterForm select[name="Year"]').val(State.data.year);
            $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            $.get(
                State.url,
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );
        });

        // handle pagination clicks
        $("body").on("click", "a.pagination", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#ArticleList").addClass("loading");
            $.get(
                $(this).attr("href"),
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    $("#ArticleList").replaceWith($(data));
                }
            );

            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The PHP part remains the same, except a small addition where we pass our desired URL pattern over to JS. I added it as an HTML5 data-property to the Dropdown field, but you could hardcode it or pass it otherwise:

```
DropdownField::create(
    'Year',
    'Year',
    $values,
    $this->getRequest()->param('ID')
)->setHasEmptyDefault(true)
    ->setEmptyString('Show all')
    ->setAttribute('data-urlpattern', $this->Link('year') . '/YYYY')
```

The benefit of this slightly more complex solution is, that it's aware of the URL. So you can navigate normally using back/forward browser buttons while still retaining full AJAX functionality.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I want! However, there is one issue...I see this error in the console: History.getState is not a function. The functionality otherwise works, but it seems to be breaking the jQuery that is meant to make the use of a submit button obsolete. I don't understand why this is. It seems like everything is set up correctly, but .getState() is throwing an error.

Comment: Did you download and add the history JS script(s)? See: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js#download--installation

Comment: I tried different ones with no success. Right now I am using history.js from the uncompressed directory. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/tree/master/scripts/uncompressed

Comment: I've used this one: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/bundled/html5/jquery.history.js … make sure to load it after jQuery and before your Script.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it!